# How to run a nodejs script every second

Tags: node.js, cron

I need to run my nodejs script for every second ,Similar to PHP cron jobs. I have tried some nodejs cron libraries like https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron but the issue was first run should be manual i:e I have to run the file with cron script for first time manually.

But in php cron jobs, they run by the server so if the apache server running script will automatically start and even if the script return an error for a cycle then script will run again from the beginning from the next cycle

So is there any way to achieve this in nodejs ?

Comment: The better way is to use sockets than to run the script every second.

Comment: If you do proper error handling your script won't break in node too. The cron library you mentioned works well, so go with that and supervisord if you need the script to run every second. It's just a question of how your application is written.

Comment: Is there any way you could use the setInterval function, or does it not fit the requirements?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. using Node as a daemon, with something like Supervisord to run your node-cron script. This alternative is wasteful on resources such as RAM because Node and Supervisord are running all the time.
2. using the system's crontab, you can run your script like calling Node on the command line, such as `* * * * node /path/to/your/script.js`. This alternative is highly efficient but lacks some control, like being able to log the output in case of an error, although you could just pipe the output to a file: `node script.js > logfile`

Comment: actually this is for a SCADA system which collect data from some factories and send those data to a REST api each second. It will return data only if we asked so we need to request data each second, and this should operate 24x7 without any hassle even if an error present in current cycle it should able to start over from the next cycle

Comment: wouldn't option 2 run every **minute** - not second?

Comment: @HPierce you're right, but it's entirely up to how the script is programmed. he could set a `setTimeout` to be called 60 times, or he could make the call 60 times separated by a `sleep(1)`. I'm just giving him the tools.